# Why are these integers being converted to random characters?

Tags: python, sqlite

When I run the following python script on a given csv file (`csv_file`), integers are converted into random characters in the sqlite3 database. I would like these integers to remain as integers when they are input into the database.

```py
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=0)
csv_fieldnames = data.columns.values

"INSERT INTO " + table + " (id, paper, name) VALUES (" + ",".join('?'*len(csv_fieldnames)) + ")"
```

**Example:**

Sample csv file:

```
id,paper,name
,7,AC-600
```

Code produces this:

```sql
id          paper       name
----------  ----------  ----------
1                      AC-600
```

When it should produce this:

```sql
id          paper       name
----------  ----------  ----------
1           7          AC-600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Pandas is way too clever (or stupid) for SQLite3. The `paper` column that you expect to contain int values receives `numpy.int64` values and **not** int values. SQLite3 processes them as plain bytes because it is an unknown type. So 7 is translated (on a little endian system) to `b'\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`, that is a back space followed with null characters that contain no printable character. And that is the reason why other values give apparently random characters.

You could manually coerce the type at insert time, or you could register an *adapter* into the sqlite3 module:

```
def adapt_int64(i):
    return int(i)

sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int64, adapt_int64)
```

After that, you can safely insert `numpy.int64` values into your `integer` column.